# iOS podcast app without fixed episode limits?

Tags: ios, podcasts

I like to listen to the archives of the BBC podcast "In our time", which contains more than 750 episodes. But I can't see the all the older episodes with Apple's app, which has a 300 episode limit. Is there any iOS app that doesn't have an episode limit and so will let me see the entire episode list and download any episode from the archive?

Answer (score 1):

300 episode limit is due to podcast host, not podcast app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a long time listener to "In Our Time" as well. Instead of subscribing to the main "In Our Time" podcast, with the 300 episode limit, you can subscribe to the five "In Our Time" podcasts of History, Philosophy, Science, Culture and Religion. As of today the episode counts for these are:-

```
In Our Time: Culture 206
In Our Time: History 265
In Our Time: Philosophy 126
In Our Time: Religion 103
In Our Time: Science 243

Total 943
```

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Our_Time_(radio_series)), "In Our Time" is currently (24.6.2018) at 808 episodes, so there must be some duplicates in those five podcasts.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Overcast](https://overcast.fm) to expand the [limit to 500 episodes](https://marco.org/2018/03/13/overcast41):

> Extremely large playlists now only show the most/least-recent 500 episodes to improve app performance for users with very high subscription counts.

## Feed, Not App, Limit

**The number of available episodes may be limited by the BBC, and not the podcast application.** The feed used by the podcast application is provided by the BBC and does not contain every episode.

### Counting Episodes in the Feed

You can prove this by downloading the [BBC In Our Time podcast RSS feed](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b006qykl/episodes/downloads). Use the following command in Terminal.app to download the complete feed:

```
curl http://podcasts.files.bbci.co.uk/b006qykl.rss > ~/Desktop/in-our-time.rss
```

Next count the number of file enclosures mentioned in the feed:

```
grep -c '<enclosure ur' ~/Desktop/in-our-time.rss
```

The result, as of answering, is `244` file enclosures.